# How to alter the value of a JsonNode while constructing it from a string in Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a JSON string and I want to alter the value while constructing the JsonNode using Jackson library. 
eg:-

```
input: {"name":"xyz","price":"90.00"}
output:{"name":"xyz-3","price":90.90}
```

I created my own JsonFactory and passed my own Parser. but I can only alter the keys, not the values associated with a key.

code:

```
private static ObjectMapper create() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory() {
            @Override
            protected JsonParser _createParser(byte[] data, int offset, int len, IOContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                return new MyParser(super._createParser(data, offset, len, ctxt));
            }

            @Override
            protected JsonParser _createParser(InputStream in, IOContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                return new MyParser(super._createParser(in, ctxt));
            }

            @Override
            protected JsonParser _createParser(Reader r, IOContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                return new MyParser(super._createParser(r, ctxt));
            }

            @Override
            protected JsonParser _createParser(char[] data, int offset, int len, IOContext ctxt, boolean recyclable)
                    throws IOException {
                return new MyParser(super._createParser(data, offset, len, ctxt, recyclable));
            }
        });

private static final class MyParser extends JsonParserDelegate {

        private MyParser(JsonParser d) {
            super(d);
        }

        @Override
        public String getCurrentName() throws IOException, JsonParseException {
            ....
        }

        @Override
        public String getText() throws IOException, JsonParseException {
           ...
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCurrentValue() {
            ...
        }


        @Override
        public String getValueAsString() throws IOException {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public String getValueAsString(String defaultValue) throws IOException {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Below is the code to construct the JsonNode from the string.

```
mapper.readTree(jsonStr);
```

In this case when the readTree method is called the `getCurrentValue` or `getValueAsString` methods are not called, so I am not able to alter the value while creating the JsonNode itself.
Also the json strings can be different. Basically I want to construct a JsonNode from the string. so tying to a specific schema/bean is not a good choice here.
How to address this ? TIA

Adding the updated code for version 2.7.4:-

```
static class MyParser extends JsonParserDelegate {
        MyParser(final JsonParser delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        @Override
        public String getText() throws IOException {
            final String text = super.getText();

            if ("name".equals(getCurrentName())) {
                return text + "-3";
            }

            return text;
        }

        @Override
        public JsonToken nextToken() throws IOException {
            if ("price".equals(getCurrentName())) {
                // Advance token anyway
                super.nextToken();
                return JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT;
            }

            return super.nextToken();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentTokenId() {
            try {
                if ("price".equals(getCurrentName())) {
                    return JsonTokenId.ID_NUMBER_FLOAT;
                }
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                //
            }

            return super.getCurrentTokenId();
        }

        @Override
        public NumberType getNumberType() throws IOException {
            if ("price".equals(getCurrentName())) {
                return NumberType.FLOAT;
            }

            return super.getNumberType();
        }

        @Override
        public float getFloatValue() throws IOException {
            return Float.parseFloat(getValueAsString("0")) + 0.09F;
        }

        @Override
        public double getDoubleValue() throws IOException {
            return Double.parseDouble(getValueAsString("0")) + 0.09D;
        }


    }
```

pom.xml:-

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What is an `output` in your case? . I am not sure this kind of work should be done on `deserialisation` layer.  You could read it normally and change values on business level. If you want to change `JSON` you can use `JSON Path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: there is a subtle difference between `2.7.*` and `2.9.*`.
While `2.9.*` is able to differentiate between `double` and `float` with

```
getDoubleValue()
getFloatValue()
```

instead `2.7.*` only uses

```
getDoubleValue()
```

even for `ID_NUMBER_FLOAT` tokens.
So, you need to decide if you want to maintain retro-compatibility or not.

You can also override both, like I did here.

---

This is all what you need for your custom `MyParser`

```
static class MyParser extends JsonParserDelegate {
    MyParser(final JsonParser delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() throws IOException {
        final String text = super.getText();

        if ("name".equals(getCurrentName())) {
            return text + "-3";
        }

        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonToken nextToken() throws IOException {
        if ("price".equals(getCurrentName())) {
            // Advance token anyway
            super.nextToken();
            return JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT;
        }

        return super.nextToken();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentTokenId() {
        try {
            if ("price".equals(getCurrentName())) {
                return JsonTokenId.ID_NUMBER_FLOAT;
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            //
        }

        return super.getCurrentTokenId();
    }

    @Override
    public NumberType getNumberType() throws IOException {
        if ("price".equals(getCurrentName())) {
            return NumberType.FLOAT;
        }

        return super.getNumberType();
    }

    @Override
    public float getFloatValue() throws IOException {
        return Float.parseFloat(getValueAsString("0")) + 0.09F;
    }

    @Override
    public double getDoubleValue() throws IOException {
       return Double.parseDouble(getValueAsString("0")) + 0.09D;
    }
}
```

Output: `{"name":"xyz-3","price":90.09}`

Your code seems fine, and it's tested and working ;)

Comment: as you can in my example the value asspciated with price is float in the output, and it is string in the input. the above solution will return string in the output

Comment: @dks551 updated. Tested and working. Do you want to add `0.09` to the float value (added anyway)?

Comment: @dks551 what's the error? I've tested it a dozen times.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Current token (VALUE_STRING) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors
 at [Source: {"name":"xyz-3","price":"90.09"}; line: 1, column: 26]

Comment: Are you sure your input price is string ?

Comment: @dks551 I've used `{"name":"xyz","price":"90.00"}`. Which version of Jackson are you using?

Comment: @dks551 confirmed. It's a version problem. I'll updated for 2.7.4, if possible. I did it with 2.9.8

Comment: @dks551 updated. The problem is 2.7.4 doesn't use `getFloatValue`, instead only `getDoubleValue` is used.

Comment: @dks551 Let me know if it is working correctly now, or if I need to adjust.

Comment: No luck with `getDoubleValue` also.

Comment: @dks551 strange, I tested with 2.7.4. Can you post the updated code you're using? Is it the same exception?

Comment: @dks551 can you post the complete Maven or Gradle dependencies? I feel you're using another version of Jackson Core. If you want I can pass you the test project I'm using, so you can verify

Comment: @dks551 you changed one thing I didn't change. `NumberType.FLOAT` to `NumberType.DOUBLE`. Go back to `NumberType.FLOAT`. Also, you're using 2.8.7. I'll check for that one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191031/discussion-between-lppedd-and-dks551).

Answer (score -1):

Are you really sure that regarding the [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) it is a good idea to mix parsing and changes within the parsed data?

If you still want to do this, you could use a [Custom Deserializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer.html) and treat your wanted field names and types the way you want it, like:

```
class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Entity> {
    public CustomDeserializer(Class<Entity> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public Entity deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException {
        String name = null;
        float price = 0;

        JsonToken currentToken = null;
        while ((currentToken = jp.nextValue()) != null) {
            switch (currentToken) {
                case VALUE_STRING:
                    switch (jp.getCurrentName()) {
                        case "name":
                            name = jp.getText() + "-3"; // change this text to whatever you want;
                            break;
                        case "price":
                            price = Float.parseFloat(jp.getText()); // parse
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return new Entity(name, price);
    }
}
```

And after **registering your custom deserializer** it works on any object mapper you want:

```
    @Test
    public void customDeserialization() throws IOException {
        // given
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(Entity.class, new CustomDeserializer(Entity.class));
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        // when
        Entity entity = mapper.readValue("{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"price\":\"90.00\"}", Entity.class);

        // then
        assertThat(entity.getName()).isEqualTo("xyz-3");
        assertThat(entity.getPrice()).isEqualTo(90f);
    }
```

Comment: what is Entity here ?

Comment: Entity is only some kind of example, consider it the class which reflects your JSON `{"name":"xyz","price":"90.00"}`. More generally the `StdDeserializer` is generic with respect to the class it generates from the given JSON.

Comment: I don't want that, my json string can be different. Basically I want to construct a JsonNode from the string.  so tying to a specific schema/bean is not a good choice here.

Comment: Oh that's essential information, please add this to your question.